# Firefox: floated containers don't shrink-wrap responsive images properly?

Tags: html, css, firefox

This is a really weird issue; I'm hoping there's some obvious CSS trick I'm missing but increasingly I'm wondering if this is a Firefox bug. The setup is this: there's a #frame DIV that's positioned absolutely on all four sides. Inside this, there's a #viewport DIV whose overflow-x is set to scroll and whose height is set to 100%. (This last bit turns out to be important.) Inside this, there's a #page_container DIV that's floated and white-space: nowrap. Finally, inside that, there's a bunch of responsive images whose max-heights are set to 100%--i.e. their height never exceeds the height of the container.

The setup is convoluted because the idea is that #viewport is scrollable, and #page_container (which should shrink-wrap all the interior images and represent their total width) moves left and right inside. (I'm hoping to use iScroll on this setup, so #page_container needs to be the right width.) In Chrome, #page_container is the right width, and when you scroll #viewport all the way to the right, you can see the end of the last image with no additional white space.

In Firefox, however, #page_container is way, way, WAY too large. #viewport scrolls well past the last image in #page_container, leaving giant swaths of additional white space. However, this only happens under the specific circumstances established by the CSS. If I set a specific height on #frame (even while leaving the absolute positioning), the white space shrinks substantially (but does not disappear). If I leave #frame alone while setting a specific height on #viewport, the white space also shrinks. If I set an explicit height on the images, the white space disappears entirely.

As far as I can tell, if you cook the CSS the way I have, Firefox shrink-wraps #page_container, but assumes all the images are FULL SIZE, not the size they've shrunk to after max-height has been applied and the container heights have been calculated. Because the images themselves have been resized properly, this leaves a ton of horizontal white space that shouldn't be there.

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/coLv0spn/2/
(version with iScroll enabled: http://jsfiddle.net/chrominance/coLv0spn/6/)

HTML:

```
<div id="frame">
    <div id="viewport">
        <div id="page_container">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/1500x1920/000/fff" />
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/1500x1920/000/f33" />
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/1500x1920/000/3f3" />
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/1500x1920/000/33f" />
            (...etc...)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#frame {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
#viewport {
    font-size: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#page_container {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
img {
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Why do you float the #page_container as well? http://jsfiddle.net/coLv0spn/4/

Comment: I had a previous version that didn't use the float, precisely because of this issue. However, when I don't use the float, Firefox reads the width of #page_container as equal to the width of #viewport, even though its content exceeds the width of #viewport. The iScroll library I want to use to allow drag-to-scroll doesn't work properly if #page_container is the same width as #viewport, unfortunately.

Comment: Here's an updated version that includes iScroll, if that helps: http://jsfiddle.net/chrominance/coLv0spn/6/ Thanks for the help so far, everyone, I do appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the Viewport is necessary, but taking it out and taking the float off the #page_container seems to work for me in Firefox. Here's a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/bnc3mn1q/7/

and the css

```
#frame {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

#page_container {
    height: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
img {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
img:last-child {
    margin-right:0;   
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I use #frame to anchor other UI elements that can't scroll with #viewport, hence the additional div.

Comment: Here's an example with a fixed UI element, but details aside the container width seems to be fixed.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bnc3mn1q/9/)